# Creating ZIP file in memory

Tags: java, zip

I need to create a ZIP file which consists of files that are created on-the-fly and have no persistence on the file system.

For example: I want to create an SQLite database in memory and after populating it with data I want to add it to a - not yet existing - ZIP file and than I want to actually write this ZIP file to the file system.

I found several approaches where the files, which are going to be the content of the archive, have to be read from the file system.

Is there actually a way to archive what I want to do? I hoped that `compress-commons` would help me but apparently they don't.

Do I miss something?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: you could create a temporary folder, save your files to it, zip them and delete it after the operation

Answer (score 3):

If the in memory object you are trying to zip is serializable, then this is quite easy.

You can take any serializable instance and turn it in to a `byte[]`. I have a utility method to do this:

```
public static byte[] convertToBytes(Object object) throws IOException {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)) {
        out.writeObject(object);
        out.flush();
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Once you have a that object represented in bytes, you can use a ZipOutputStream to zip it up:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
         GZIPOutputStream out = new GZIPOutputStream(bos); ) {
    out.write(bytes);
    out.finish();
    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray(); // this is my compressed data
}
```

(I use Gzip here for simplicity but you can also create a zip with multiple entries, for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it possible to have several files in different folders with this approach? I do want to have an in-memory solution due to the fact that some of the files shall be encrypted and there should not be an unencrypted version of the file on the file system.

Comment: If you mean to have a directory structure inside the zip, then yes, I believe that is possible by using [ZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) with the appropriate ZipEntry objects.